# Children boxes not vertically centred in Safari 9

Tags: html, css, safari

In the following snippet, `.inner1` and `.inner2` are not strictly vertically centred in `.outer`. I've used Safari's builtin web inspector, but I found no margin between the boxes.

```css
.outer {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid silver;
}
.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 10px;
}
.inner1 {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
.inner2 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <span class="inner inner1"></span>
  <span class="inner inner2"></span>
</div>
```

What prevents the boxes from touching each other, and how can I fix this?

I'm using Safari 9.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is white-space on `inline-block` elements and one way to remove it is to remove white space in `HTML` between elements.

```css
.outer {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid silver;
}
.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 10px;
}
.inner1 {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.inner2 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <span class="inner inner1"></span><span class="inner inner2"></span>
</div>
```

You can also use `Flexbox` to remove white-space and get `vertical-align` of child elements.

```css
.outer {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.inner {
  margin: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 10px;
}
.inner1 {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.inner2 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <span class="inner inner1"></span>
  <span class="inner inner2"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems that it's still not strictly centred...(I'm using Safari 9.1.2): https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQW0w.png

Comment: I cannot test it on safari but try this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1273/

Comment: It would be nice if you can explain why `display: forinline-block` fails. Is this a bug of Safari?

Answer (score 1):

You can used flexbox for that:

```css
.outer {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  height:25px;
  align-items: center;
}
.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 10px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.inner1 {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
.inner2 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <span class="inner inner1"></span><span class="inner inner2"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems that it's still not *strictly* centred...(I'm using Safari 9.1.2): https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuhJO.png

Comment: Thanks! Also, it would be nice if you can explain why `display: forinline-block` fails.